# Error when adding new Nuget to a .Net Standard Project

Tags: nuget-package-restore

I am working on referencing another set of .dlls in another project and have bundled it up via Nuget:

I get this error:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1701  Package 'MyPackageImTryingToInstall' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.        1**

I understand the error, but how do I make .Nuget restore with .Net standard?

Just found that if I reference the Nuget in a .Net Framework 4.6.1 project - it works fine.

It has something to do with making a nuget from .net standard to .net standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add lib folders for the target frameworks I wanted to add the nuget package to:

For the files section in the nuspec I needed to make a \netstandard2.0 folder and \461 folder